# Characters Found at the end of SQL Statement -- Access Database

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I am working in a windows application which has access database. I am inserting records using `OleDbTransaction` and other classes.
When I run my code I get the error message:

> Characters Found at the end of SQL Statement

I am inserting 10 records in a transaction. It is not allowing me to insert multiple insert statements of a same table inside a single transaction. Is there any drawback that in access we cannot use multiple insert statements of a same table?

Below is my code block:

strQueries is a dictionary which has a collection of insert statements seprated by semicolon(;)

```
oleDbTran = accessDbConnection.BeginTransaction();
cmdReturnValue.Transaction = oleDbTran;
foreach (var query in strQueries)
{
    cmdReturnValue.CommandText = query.Value.ToString();
    cmdReturnValue.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

oleDbTran.Commit();
```

Comment: You really should post your SQL statement if you want us to help

Comment: If I recall correctly, Access limits you to a single statement per call.  TO test this, you could try running a few INSERTs directly (i.e. using MS Access) into an Access database.

Comment: Why not insert the 10 rows to the same table in one insert statement?  `INSERT INTO TABLE(...) VALUES (...), (...), (...)`

Comment: Thank You all. Really Appreciate your responses. 
@ Juharr,
Can you please provide me a sample query for the same?

Comment: Does your code work with 2 `INSERT` statements instead of 10?  If not, please show us the text from those 2 statements.

Comment: No HansUp, If I try to execute more than 1 insert statements of a same table inside a single transaction, it does not allow me to insert.

Answer (score 0):

> INSERT INTO TABLE(...) VALUES (...), (...), (...)

This is **not** an accepted Access (Jet) SQL syntax. What is it, MySQL? Anyway. If you need this syntax, because you have connected your front-end (the Access application) to a back-end (the database containing your data) using ODBC that supports this syntax, you can consider using [pass-through queries](https://www.google.ch/search?q=access+pass-through+query). Access does not try to interpret those; instead it will send it to the backend as-is.